# Uncaught TypeError: icon.hasName is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a console error "Uncaught TypeError: icon.hasName is not a function" when I'm using my mobile navigation using the hamburger menu and I'm not sure how to get rid of this or solve it. Any ideas?[image: Error message]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you have to create the function .addName first and tell it what to do so it can carry it out on the varyable also you may be able do get to work by changing it to addName(icon)
this makes sure the function is applied to the variable